# JSMPP - EnquireLinkTimer, session dies after long time inactivity

Tags: java, session, sms, smpp, jsmpp

What is `enquireLinkTimer` property in `SMPPSession` class from JSMPP library? It rebings session every N milliseconds? If not, is there a way to automatically rebing session with some time interval?

Or what should I do, if I face the following problem: when for a long time there're no messages to send, I think session dies (I got `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` ) and then messages don't send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enquireLinkTimer` keeps your connection to SMSC alive by sending keep-alive-messages to it. But it cannot rebring/reconnect a broken connection.

Maybe the SMSC decides after a while to close the connection because you didn't send SMS for a while. You have to reconnect manually by discarding your old session and creating a new one.

If you want to reconnect immediately you can set up a state Change Listener  to your session:

```
yourSession.addSessionStateListener(new SessionStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChange(SessionState newState, SessionState oldState,
                                          Object source)
    {
        if (newState == SessionState.CLOSED) {
            /* throw away old session and create a new one */
        }
    }
}
```